# Iterating through object by object's nested element order

Tags: jquery

Having a very large collection of objects structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "job": "cop",
    "city": "london"
  },
  {
    "name": "mike",
    "job": "nurse",
    "city": "las vegas"
  },
  {
    "name": "kate",
    "job": "teacher",
    "city": "london"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to iterate through them in order of `city`. Pseudo-code:

```
For each city
    print some extra city info
    For each person in city
        print person info
    next
    print some other extra city info
next
```

I know how to do this in a complicated way; is there a simple one using JQuery?

Comment: please share what ever you have tried

Comment: Could you show the actual data structures, not some generic description of them. Is the collection an array? Use `sort` to sort it by city, then use `jQuery.each()` to iterate over them.

Comment: @ArunPJohny The way I would do it would be very hacky and long, so I haven't tried it yet (also because I know it WILL work). I'm looking for the simpler/best way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar Question amended to include the actual data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort the info by city:

```
info.sort(function(i1, i2{
    if (i1 < i2) {
        return 1;
    } else if (i1 > i2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Then iterate over the elements, printing the city info whenever it changes.

```
var last_city = null;
$.each(info, function(i, el) {
    if (el.city != last_city) {
        // print extra city info
    }
    // print person info
    if (el.city != last_city) {
        // print more city info
        last_city = el.city;
    }
});
```

Comment: As easy as that. Thank you!